# How to dynamic override function c# in runtime

Tags: c#

im learning c# and i have problems with dynamic override , im trying to use and array of nations populed with different nation and if a specific nation appear i want to use a specific function of that class .

Abstract Class:

```
public abstract class Nazione
{
    int population;
    String name;

    public Nazione(int p, string n)
    {
        population = p;
        name = n;
    }

    public virtual int getPopulation() { return population; }

    public string getName() { return name; }
}
```

Overridden classes:

```
public class Italy : Nazione
{
    public Italy() : base (22391392,"Italia") {}
    public override int getPopulation()
    {
        return base.getPopulation();
    }
    public string Greetings() { return "Ciao"; }
}  

public class Germany : Nazione
{
    public Germany() : base(3428272,"Germania") { }
    public override int getPopulation()
    {
        return base.getPopulation()/2;
     }
}
```

Main:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Nazione[] c = new Nazione[20];
            c[0] = new Italy();
            c[1] = new Germany();

            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                if(c[i].getName()=="Italia")
                {
                   c[i].Greetings(); // this doesn't work :( 
                }
                Console.WriteLine(c[i].getPopulation());

            }
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

I cannot call `italy.Greetings()` in runtime there is some scope error but i can't see it , thanks for your help .

Comment: Try `(c[i] as Italy).Greetings()`.

Comment: @HaZe Answer your question yourself and mark it as answer to help others having the same problem. The system will not allow you to mark as answer for 8 hours. So you can mark it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following in your example:

```
if(c[i].getName() == "Italia")
{
    ((Italy)c[i]).Greetings(); 
}
```

Or this is what I would do:

```
var italy = c[i] as Italy;
if(italy != null)
{
   italy.Greetings();
}
```